# Stopping focus changed event being handled multiple times in one second

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a focus changed event handler (uia) on a background MTA thread for updating a list of elements for the current active window which gets fired multiple times in one second when changing active window. I am trying to make it to go once and then wait for one second before handling any other events. Problem at the minute is that the timer is started but never triggered? I guess there is a better way of doing this? A code example would be great.

```
public void HandleFocusChangedEvent(IUIAutomationElement sender)
{

    // A focus changed event has been sent by the the active window or some descendant of it.

    // Check that this event hasn't arrived around the time we're removing the event handler on shutdown.
    if (!_fAddedEventHandler)
    {
        return;
    }

    // All the event handler needs to do is notify the main UI thread that the 
    // list of elements should be refreshed to make sure it's showing the most current list.
    // We only want to do this once every second So use a timer/counter
    if (focusChangedCounter == 0)
    { 

   controllerDispatcher.BeginInvoke(_focusChangedEventHandlerDelegate);
        focusChangedCounter = 1;


        if (focusChangedBufferTimer == null)
        {

            focusChangedBufferTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            focusChangedBufferTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(focusChangedBufferTimer_Tick);
            focusChangedBufferTimer.Interval = 1000;
            focusChangedBufferTimer.Start();

        }

    }
}

private void focusChangedBufferTimer_Tick ( object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    focusChangedCounter = 0;
    focusChangedBufferTimer.Stop();
    focusChangedBufferTimer = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: With each event trigger, reset the timer.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    Timer t = new Timer();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        t.Interval = 1000;
        t.Tick += ((ss, ee) => {
            t.Enabled = false;
            focusChangedCounter = 0;
            focusChangedBufferTimer.Stop();
            focusChangedBufferTimer = null;
        });
    }

    private void HandleFocusChangedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t.Enabled = false;
        t.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the code I posted above is from the focuschangedeventhandler.cs class, including the timer event handler and not from the main UI? Sorry I should have made that more clear

Comment: no problems, I understood, but I put just one example, I think you can apply the same logic

Comment: So do we need the 2 different timers, surely it can be done with one and without the counter, so presumably I would just take them out of your code above? And then just restrict all the code to the main UI

Comment: Okay got there in the end with a variation of your idea on the main UI. Thanks.

Comment: very good! Sorry for not paying attention, I've been busy. Thank you